# Creating a menu (overwrite previous output)

Tags: python, console, overwrite

I want to create a menu in Python that will show something like this:

```
-----Help menu-----

Hello and welcome to the help menu!

Press Enter to continue.
```

The hard part is that I want the previous output (from 'hello' to 'continue') to disappear. So when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> this will show up instead:

```
-----Help menu-----

The first step is to.... 

Press Enter to continue.
```

I have tried to use `\r` but that didn't allow me to use the `Press Enter` thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want just using a Clear Screen.

If you are on windows just do that on your python code:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

If you are on Linux (what you probably want to) just do that:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

With that you will be able to clear the previous output from the screen and insert the new one.

Comment: Im on a mac actually. Can i use the same code as on windows/linux?

Comment: Yes, the same commands that you use on linux, you use it on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to 'clear' the terminal is to simply put in a bunch of carriage returns to push everything else off the screen.

```
messages = ['step 1', 'step 2', 'step 3']
for m in messages:
    print('\n'*50)
    print('-----Help menu-----')
    print(m)
    input('Press Enter to continue')
```